# Using session variable with ASP.Net membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, aspnetdb

I m using the Asp.net membership provider with my web application !

I would like to know how to get the user ID and How and Where can I add code to the application to set same session variable On the User log on !
This is the scenario :
The user Logon,
I catch his ID an the database
I execute some query to set same session variable with data in relation with this user : Like name and other stuff from other table in relation with the user table !
According to user data(role and other stuff), I redirects it to his own view or page.

Thank you for helping me !

PS :The membership system are using his own database : ASPNETDB.mdf !
PSS: I m using C sharp !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey` is what you're looking for. Why do you want to store it in Session?

Comment: Thank you !

Is not the Key i would like to store but with this key i can get some information form the data base !

Other think, Where can I catch the event of the user logon ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you want to store the Username in the Session rather than the user key from the membership database?

I had the same problem, you cannot get it from the Membership objects. You need to store it when the user logs in. If your using an asp:Login control, you can add store it using the OnLoggedIn event:

```
protected void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["username"] = Login1.UserName;
}
```